# Database error (MongoTimeoutException) Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector

Tags: mongodb

Whenever I am doing an operation (CRUD) on the primary database, I'm getting the following error:

```
Database error (MongoTimeoutException): Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server
that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET,
servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, roundTripTime=0.3 ms,
 state=CONNECTED}]
```

My primary and replica database are configured as follows:

First kill all mongoDB processes.
Start three terminals.

```
mongod --replSet rs0 --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --port 27017
mongod --replSet rs0 --dbpath C:\Data\db2 --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --port 27018

mongo --port 27017
use test
config = {_id : "rs0", members : [{_id : 0, host : "127.0.0.1:27017"},          
         {_id : 1, host : "127.0.0.1:27018"}]}
rs.initiate(config)
```

The annoying part is that it works sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't. If it doesn't work, it works again after I restart my computer.